# placing chart next to each other with .left

Tags: visual-studio-2010, excel, vba

I tried to place 2 chart next to each other with .left when it creats but i dosent work. what have i miss?

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Diagram").ChartObjects.Add(200, 200, 600, 400).Chart
    .Parent.Name = Name
    .left = 400

    If Not .HasTitle Then
        .HasTitle = True
        .ChartTitle.Text = Name
    End If

    .ChartType = xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers
    .Axes(xlValue).CrossesAt = CrossAt
    .Axes(xlCategory).TickLabels.NumberFormat = "YYYY-MM-DD"

    For i = LBound(sXRanges) To UBound(sXRanges)
        With .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
            .Name = country(i)
            .XValues = sXRanges(i)
            .Values = sYRanges(i)
        End With
    Next
End With
```

Comment: The first parameter of `ChartObjects.Add` is the left property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.Left` isn't a property of the Chart you are referencing.
What you actually want to use is the ChartObject `.Parent.Left`

Comment: thx its working with .Parent.left but both chart still place on each other. :(

Comment: If you want them to be side by side, and do not resize them and keep the `.Parent.Left = 400` for the first chart... Use `.Parent.Left = 1000` for the 2nd. However, as the comments indicated the first parameter of `ChartObject.Add` assigns the left value, so you do not need to indicate it afterwards. Just make sure that the left of chart2 is >= to the left of chart1 plus the width of chart 1, this will keep them from overlapping. Based on your method call, that is the 1st(left) and 3rd(width) parameter.

Comment: thx Daniel and Head of Catering. i solved it. and understand about chart much more now. the first paramter in add chart is left. and the second is top.i can even use .parent.left or parent.top. i solved it by using a variable for add(position,2,600,400) and the first chart get position 2 (left = 2) and the second get position 604 (left = 604). so now they r created side by side :)